# IIS7 & CakePHP error index.php file not found

Tags: php, windows, cakephp, iis-7

i am setting up cakephp app on a windows server running iis7. PHP is installed and everything works when accessing controller/action etc but when going to the root of the site / i get index.php file not found error but if i type index.php?url=controller/action it redirects fine, does any one have any suggestions? i have looked every where and used all sorts of URL Rewrite files but nothing works any help would be appreciated, thanks! :D

Comment: Can't do much without more info. Post your rewrite rules and we'll see.

Comment: You might have better luck at http://serverfault.com

Comment: Have you turned on Microsoft URL Rewriter?

Comment: was sorted - found answer at iis.net, just searched cakephp index.php issues on there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was sorted - found answer at iis.net, just searched cakephp index.php issues on there